# Setup.py install doesn't work as expected??? or is it?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

So, i have written a program in Python with the following structure:

```
project/
 | doc/
 | project/
    | __init__.py
    | other packages
    | tests
       | __init__.py
       | other test files
 |
 | AllTest.py
 | README
 | License
 | setup.py
```

My `setup.py` file looks as the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys


# dependencies
INSTALL_REQUIRES = ['numpy>1.0.0',
                    'matplotlib',
                    'scipy'
                ]


setup(name='project',
      version='0.9',
      author='Some Author',
      description = ("Working Project for claculating something"),
      packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
      install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
      test_suite="AllTest.py",
     )
```

My `AllTest.py` looks like this:

```
import unittest

# run all tests in current dir matching the pattern
#if __name__ == "__main__":
def additional_tests():
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover('project/test', pattern='*.py')
```

My problem is: if i run `python setup.py install` in the driectory i have my project and the `setup.py` file a new directory `build` is created with all of my files in. In my `\Python3.x\Lib\site-packages` is only an `.egg` file created, the `.egg` file has a `.zip` file of my project.

I'm not sure if that's all that has to be done, or i am making some mistakes.

Comment: Once you've installed it, can you `import project` in a Python 3 interpreter? I found this a useful introduction to getting the project set up right: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: yes, that works just fine.
Thanks for your tutorial, that's a lot of help, since i am pretty new to python and setup.py

Comment: Then why do you think there's a problem at all?

Comment: I didn't know how to verify if my setup.py install has done what i've wanted. Thanks again